# Adding a view loaded from a NIB to a Custom Table View Cell doesn't work as expected

Tags: ios, swift, subview, uitableview

I have been playing around with reusing views inside a table view cell. I have a custom table view cell and another reusable view that I use in the cell and in other parts of my app. The reusable view is defined in a XIB file and linked accordingly with it's class definition.

I am having strange behaviour when I try to get the view inside a custom table view cell

DevicesTableViewCell <- Custom UITableViewCell to hold a view that is in another NIB.

DeviceView <- Custom reusable view that can be used in a cell and in other parts of the app, like a Stack View.

Now, when I try to load the nib and add it to the Cells Content View, the view doesn't appear. However if I try to add it to a container view inside the table view cell, it does work.

Cell setup code :

```
    let devicesName         = sectionDataArray[MasterSection.devices.rawValue].reuseId
    let devicesNib          = UINib(nibName: devicesName, bundle: nil)
    tableView.register(devicesNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: devicesName)
```

1. Code where view does not appear :

   ```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: sectionDataArray[indexPath.section].reuseId)

   print ("-- Showing devices cell")
   let deviceCell = cell as! DevicesTableViewCell

   // Optimise this, we way not necessarily need to load this view every single time
   if deviceCell.deviceView == nil {
       deviceCell.deviceView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("DeviceView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! DeviceView
       deviceCell.containerView.isHidden = true
       deviceCell.contentView.addSubview(deviceCell.deviceView)

       let views = ["deviceView" : deviceCell.deviceView]

       deviceCell.deviceView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

       deviceCell.contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[deviceView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views))
       deviceCell.contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[deviceView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views))
   }

   // TODO - Setup cell data contents

   return deviceCell
   }
   ```
2. Code where view does appear :

   ```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: sectionDataArray[indexPath.section].reuseId)

   print ("-- Showing devices cell")
   let deviceCell = cell as! DevicesTableViewCell

   // Optimise this, we way not necessarily need to load this view every single time
   if deviceCell.deviceView == nil {
       deviceCell.deviceView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("DeviceView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! DeviceView
       //deviceCell.containerView.isHidden = true
       deviceCell.containerView.addSubview(deviceCell.deviceView)

       let views = ["deviceView" : deviceCell.deviceView]

       deviceCell.deviceView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

       deviceCell.containerView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[deviceView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views))
       deviceCell.containerView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[deviceView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views))
   }

   // TODO - Setup cell data contents

   return deviceCell
   }
   ```

Custom Cell Code :

```
class DevicesTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
var deviceView: DeviceView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

RESULT:

1. Adding to contentView -> Nothing appears but a white background.
2. Adding to containerView -> The view appears as normal and is contained in the cell with the correct auto layout constraints internally.

NOTES:
The containerView is in the Custom Table Cell View XIB file. Container view has autolayout constraints bounding its view to the table view cell view with margins of 0.

QUESTION: 
Can anyone explain why in this particular case the Content view does not correctly display its subviews ?

Comment: i think your container view is hidden in your first part of code check this line   deviceCell.containerView.isHidden = true just try to change your code   deviceCell.containerView.isHidden = false cell is drawing but container is hidden so cell can't show its content.

Comment: That's correct, container view is hidden because it sits on top of the content view, this is why I add subviews to the content view and hide the container view.

Comment: But the content view does not show anything. In the second case I add the subviews to the container view which works.

Comment: but i think you are showing your content inside containerView and when containerView is hidden all its subviews are automatically hidden

Comment: @dragoneye I found the problem. The XIB file was setup wrong, check my answer. Please up vote. :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I had the wrong object inside the XIB file.

Inside the DevicesTableViewCell.xib, the view created was a UIView object. Not a UITableViewCell object.

If you instantiate a cell from a XIB, make sure that view object is created from a UITableViewCell.

This is because the UITableViewCell object has a content view wrapped inside it.

After changing the XIB file adding objects to the content view worked correct.

Comment: The easiest way to get the right xib that includes a contentView is to create a UITableViewCell class from scratch in Xcode and check the "also create xib file" option.